# How to I prevent a Standard user from booting into Safe Mode?

Tags: administrator, parental-controls, safe-mode

I am the admin of my son's Mac. When he boots into Safe Mode, the parental control software is disabled and I am not able to block certain apps, or websites or track his web activities. Apple Screen Time doesn't provide the kind of information I get from the 3rd-party parental control software.

Comment: Which specific Mac model is your son using?

Comment: I would look at getting an Internet router with parental controls so no matter the device or what gets bypassed, those restrictions will remain in place. The only way around it will be to find a different network.